# Java 8 stream group by min and max

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Suppose you run an SQL query against an employees table:

```
SELECT department, team, MIN(salary), MAX(salary)
  FROM employees
 GROUP BY department, team
```

And in the java client you map the result set to a list of `Aggregate` instances by making a DAO call like below:

```
List<Aggregate> deptTeamAggregates = employeeDao.getMinMaxSalariesByDeptAndTeam()
```

And 'Aggregate' has getter methods for department, team, minSalary, maxSalary and there is a `Pair<T, T>` tuple

What would be the clearest and possible the most optimal way to map the result set into the two maps below:

```
Map<String, Pair<Integer, Integer>> byDepartmentMinMax = ...
Map<Pair<String, String>, Pair<Integer, Integer>> byDepartmentAndTeamMinMax  = ...
```

I know I could map my result set in a different way and/or make two trips to the database and achieve the same thing in an easier way but I am more about understanding the java 8 capabilities.

Thank you in advance for your inputs.

Comment: Why are you using `Pair` instead of a class with actual names for the relevant fields?

Comment: Just keeping my example simpler. Of course you could call it `Range` but this would not alter in any way the problem I am trying to solve

Comment: `Map<<String, String>, Pair<Integer, Integer>>` -> `Map<Pair<String, String>, Pair<Integer, Integer>>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    class Pair<T, U> {
        public final T x;
        public final U y;

        public Pair(T x, U y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    Collector<Aggregate, ?, Pair<Integer, Integer>> aggregateSalary = 
        mapping(a -> new Pair<>(a.getMinSalary(), a.getMaxSalary()),
            reducing(new Pair<>(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE),
                (a, b) -> new Pair<>(Math.min(a.x, b.x), Math.max(a.y, b.y))));

    Map<String, Pair<Integer, Integer>> byDepartmentMinMax =
        deptTeamAggregates.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(a -> a.getDepartment(), aggregateSalary));

    Map<Pair<String, String>, Pair<Integer, Integer>> byDepartmentAndTeamMinMax =
        deptTeamAggregates.stream()
            .collect(toMap(a -> new Pair<>(a.getDepartment(), a.getTeam()), a -> new Pair<>(a.getMinSalary(), a.getMaxSalary())));
```

Comment: correct solution. but SQL for `byDepartmentMinMax` is much more concise: `SELECT department, MIN(salary), MAX(salary)
  FROM employees
 GROUP BY department`

Comment: @Julian I have posted all of my code.  See [here](https://paiza.io/projects/Zef-FiV5csI5dvpoBBrlxA?locale=en-us).

Comment: That was exactly what I was after. Thank you very much. In case you read it sorry for my earlier comment saying the code did not compile. It is my version of intelij that seems not to understand lambdas very well. For those interested in reading further I also found [this solution](http://blog.jooq.org/2015/01/23/how-to-translate-sql-group-by-and-aggregations-to-java-8/) on the internet.

However your solution is clearer and I liked it more.