# max or min value on the basis of group by in stream java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Seems similar to previously answered question:[Java 8 stream group by min and max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958516/java-8-stream-group-by-min-and-max)

However it is not!

I have a table with Three Columns:
`LogId, StartTime, EndTime`

Now We have Multiple entries of same LogId with different StartTime and EndTime

The problem is:

1. All the columns I have are String, so How to calculate min or max of any column based on their values.
2. I need to Find out min(StartTime), max(EndTime) group by LogId into a single Stream.

How can this be achieved with minimal code and maximal efficiency using stream in java 8.

Attached is the Sample class:

```
public class Log {  

    private static final String inputFileName = "D:\\path\\to\\Log.csv";

    private static final String outputFileName = "D:\\path\\to\\Output\\Log.csv";

    private static List<Log> logList = null;

    private static Map<String, List<Log>> groupByLogId = new HashMap<String, List<Log>>();

    private String log_Id;
    private String startTime;
    private String endTime;

    public static Map<String, List<Log>> createLogMap() throws IOException {
        Function<String, Log> mapToLog = (line) -> {
            String[] p = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);
            Log log = new Log(p[0],p[1],
                    p[2]);

            return log;
        };


        InputStream is = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

            is = new FileInputStream(new File(inputFileName));

            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            logList = br.lines()
                            .skip(1)
                            .map(mapToLog)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());




            logList.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

            groupByLogId = logList.stream()
                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Log::getLog_Id));


            for (Entry<String, List<Log>> entryForLog : groupByLogId.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(" Entity Id " + entryForLog.getKey()
                        + "        |        Value : " + entryForLog.getValue());
            }






            br.close();
            return groupByLogId;



    }



    public String getLog_Id() {
        return log_Id;
    }



    public void setLog_Id(String log_Id) {
        this.log_Id = log_Id;
    }



    public String getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }



    public void setStartTime(String startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }



    public String getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }



    public void setEndTime(String endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }



    public static List<Log> getLoglist() {
        return logList;
    }



    public Log(String log_Id, String startTime, String endTime) {
        super();
        this.log_Id = log_Id;
        this.startTime = startTime;
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return (new StringBuffer()
                    .append(log_Id).append(",")
                    .append(startTime).append(",")
                    .append(endTime)
                    ).toString();

    }


}
```

Any help is much appreciated,

Expected Output:

`LogId: logid,min(StartTime),max(EndTime)`

Comment: "How can this be achieved with minimal code and maximal efficiency using stream in java 8." - I find it too broad, please try to be more specific with your question.

Comment: try use `map` to `int/long` before `group`

Comment: That code looks *ancient*. You should use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`, but actually, using simply `log_Id+","+startTime+","+endTime` gives you the benefit automatically. Your more complicated `toString()` implementation offers no benefit over the simple expression. Further, you should use the `try( …) { … }` statement to manage resources. No need to manually call `close()` and the problem that you are not closing correctly in the exceptional case is gone. Further, you don’t need to repeat type argument anymore: `groupByLogId=new HashMap<>()` will infer the type from the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, storing time as string is not very good idea. It would be better to use something like `LocalDateTime` instead. In this answer I assume that your string timestamp representations are comparable so I can use `date1.compareTo(date2)`.

Also I strongly recommend you to remove setters making the `Log` objects immutable. They don't add any value, only make your program harder to debug when you occasionally change existing objects.

Back to your question, add a merger method like this:

```
class Log {
    ...
    Log merge(Log other) {
        if(!other.getLog_Id().equals(this.getLog_Id())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        String start = this.getStartTime().compareTo(other.getStartTime()) < 0 ?
                       this.getStartTime() : other.getStartTime();
        String end = this.getEndTime().compareTo(other.getEndTime()) > 0 ?
                     this.getEndTime() : other.getEndTime();
        return new Log(this.getLog_Id, start, end);
    }
}
```

Now you can simply use `toMap()` collector supplying your merge function:

```
streamOfLogs.collect(
    Collectors.toMap(Log::getLog_Id, Function.identity(), Log::merge));
```

This way when two log entries with the same `Log_Id` appear, the `merge` method will be called for both of them creating the merged log entry.